# In FB CAPI returns error 190 (expired access token) but the token is valid

Tags: api, facebook

I send post with CURL but i receive an error 190. I checked the token and the status is: valid. Actualy this type of token never expire.
I tried diferent events: Purchase, ViewContent ...
Is it possible I send it in wrong way?

Here is the error that i receive:

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AB5GS2ZXbhVL_94rXqDUaN5"}}
```

Here is the code that i use:

```
    <?
$userphone=hash('sha256','0888233361') ;

  $urlzafb="https://www.proba.com/testcurl.php" ;

$model="12345678" ;

$tokena = 'I removed the token, but it is valid';

  $clientip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$USER_AGENT=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$sega=strtotime("now") ;

$cenapxl= 24 ; 



$post_data=array(

'access_token' => '$tokena',

 'action_source' => 'website',

 'event_name' => 'ViewContent',

'event_time' => '$sega',

'custom_data' => array("currency"=>"BGN","value"=>$cenapxl),

'event_source_url' => '$urlzafb=',

'user_data' => 
array("ph"=>"$userphone","client_ip_address"=>"$clientip","client_user_agent"=>"$USER_AGENT"),

'contents' => array("id"=>"product123","quantity"=>1),

 'test_event_code' => 'TEST4567',
  'fbc'=> 'fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890',
  'fbp'=> 'fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397',

);  



  $ch = curl_init();

  // set url

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/424162018178777/events");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

  $response=curl_exec($ch);

  if($response === FALSE){echo "Greshka ". curl_error($ch); }



  curl_close($ch);          

print_r($response); 
?>
'''
```

Here is the status of the token: [link to the pic with the status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P7Vh.jpg)